# Duplicate Key when inserting multiple entries with incremented ids on before insert in Node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, duplicates, increment, hana

Recently I encountered a problem. I'll try to describe it as good and easy as possible.

On a BEFORE INSERT handler, I get only the body, and for generation of the id I get next available number that is divided by 10, from the already existing entries in the DB, and I assign it to the new entry that is being inserted.

The problem is that when I am trying to make a BATCH and do multiple request at once, it fails with a Duplicate Key error.

I am using HanaDB, node.js, with cds custom handler before insert, but as far as I have been looking, this issue is not related in particular with any of the technologies that I am using.

Does anyone have an idea how I can avoid this, but still keeping the logic for incremented ids?
(I only have access to the BEFORE INSERT handler, as far as I know)

Let's say I have a UserItems table with one entry. (Composed PK from USER and ITEM)

```
USER    ITEM    DESCRIPTION

1001    10      nice description
```

Now I want to add 2 more user items in parallel so the output will be like this:

```
USER    ITEM    DESCRIPTION

1001    10      nice description
1001    20      nice description 2
1001    30      nice description 3
```

But since this is made through a custom handler (middleware) which gets the next number that is divided by 10 available (20, and 30 after that) and because the requests are made in parallel, it throws me Duplicate Key error.

Basically the middleware looks at the existing data, it gets the id 20, inserts one entry, but when the other request comes for the 3rd User Item, when the code will be looking in the database to get the other id it will only see one entry

```
1001    10      nice description
```

and will get as the next available id 20 as well, but it is not ok because it will be assigned to the previous entry.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and appropriate database tag would all help your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the classic problem of hand-rolled ID generation.
A well-established approach to avoid this kind of problem is to either make use of *autogenerated-keys/sequences* or using *GUIDs*.

Trying to guarantee ordered and gap-less sequences in shared data structures (database tables) requires locking in some form. 
This makes it a bottle-neck for processing INSERTs in your application.

The mentioned *sequences* work lock-less and only guarantee unique, increasing numbers, but not that those numbers will be gap-less. 
If there is no inherent meaning besides uniqueness to the IDs in your application, then using sequences is the easiest way to do that.

And of course, you are right with the notion that this has nothing to do with the tech-products you use. This problem is a direct consequence of the transaction model that you use here.